# ¿Cómo filtrar resultados LDAP por usuario y grupo en bash?

Tags: bash, openldap

Estoy preparando un script para el trabajo en `bash`, dado que constantemente tengo que hacer consultas sobre un conjunto de usuarios y es un engorro ir toqueteando la `query` en Softerra (sobre todo cuando tienes un listado de 300 usuarios).

La idea es que pasándole un fichero `.csv` con los usuarios y los grupos donde deben estar, generar una tercera columna que indique si el usuario está en ese grupo o no.

Hasta ahora solo consigo filtrar o por usuario o por grupo, pero no por ambas cosas. Esta es la sentencia en bash:

```
ldapsearch -H ${ldphost} -u ${ldpuser} -w ${ldppswd} -x -LLL -b ${ldpbase} '(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName='${user}')(|
                (memberOf=CN=group_for_test)
))' 1.1
```

Este comando me devuelve el dn del usuario que le he pasado por parámetro en `${user}`. Lo que quiero conseguir es pasarle también el nombre del grupo como parámetro para ir iterando con un bucle.

¿Hay alguna forma de hacer dicha consulta? El nombre del grupo no está completo en el fichero. Es decir, si es: `group_for_test,cn=example,cn=domain` en el fichero solo aparece `group_for_test`.